# Use Susy & breakpoints via Bundler with Gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, breakpoints, susy

I am trying to install [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) and [Breakpoints](http://breakpoint-sass.com/) with [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) via Gulp.
How do I do this?

In the Susy docs, it says the following:

1) Put the following in your gem file:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'susy'
```

2) Put the following in config/application.rb

```
require 'susy'
```

3) Then run the following in the command line

```
bundle install
```

I have done all of this. In my gulp file (see full file [here](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/299gpx3s/)), I have the following:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return sass('frontend/build/scss/', {style: 'expanded', bundleExec: true})
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('frontend/dist/css/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('frontend/dist/css'))
    .pipe(notify({ // Add gulpif here
           sound: "Pop"
    }));
});
```

But when I run gulp, it says:

> [14:53:18] frontend/dist/js/main.js reloaded.
>
> [14:53:18] frontend/dist/scripts/main.min.js reloaded.
>
> [14:53:18] gulp-ruby-sass stderr: OptionParser::NeedlessArgument: needless argument: --sourcemap=none
>     Use --trace for backtrace.
>
> [14:53:18] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification]
>
> [14:53:18] Finished 'styles' after 592 ms
>
> [14:53:18] Starting 'default'...
>
> [14:53:18] Finished 'default' after 6.02 μs*

The css is compiled, but it has the following error message:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
```

How can I fix it, so I can run Susy and Breakpoints via Bundler with Gulp?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually using Rails?

Comment: @cimmanon I've got all the Gems installed on my Mac. If you are using Gulp, then do you still use the gems installed? I'm not 100% clear on that bit. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  If you're not using Rails, then you're not following the correct instructions.  Using Sass with Rails is a little different than using Sass on its own.

Comment: @cimmanon So the instructions on the Susy website are for Sass with rails? How do you use it without Rails? Thanks!